# (Angular 5) - Why the for of typescript only takes the last number

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I'm working with angular 5 and i have two arrays inside my component:

*Array of data*

```
data = [{...},{...}]
```

*Array of numbers*

```
inputData = [{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]
```

so the problem with this is because I want to change some values inside the `data` array with the values inside the `inputData`.

For that i´m using for iterator like this:

```
for (let x in this.data) {
  this.result = this.data[x].ranges;

  for (let y in this.result) {

    for (let z of this.inputData) {
      this.data[x].ranges[y].ph = z;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is because the for iterator makes all the operations to change that values but  when i put `console.log(data)` the data array only has the last value (`3`) of the inputData:

```
    [ 
      { "name": "Low", "ph": 3, "day": 0 },  <- Check the ph value
      { "name": "Medium", "ph": 3, "day": 0 }, <- Check the ph value
      { "name": "High", "ph": 3, "day": 0 }  <- Check the ph value
    ]
```

I created an stackblitz to show the problem in execution ([Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojsg5h))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `in` to `of`.

'of' iterates over objects, such as an array.

'in' iterates over object properties.

Here are two examples:

[image]

Also, I looked at your stackblitz ... the logic is not quite right. Try this:

```
  constructor() {
    for (let x of this.data) {
      this.result = x.ranges;

      for (let y in this.result) {
          this.result[y].ph = this.inputValues[y];
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a fork of your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckdrqe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Your original code:

```
for (let x in this.data) {
  this.result = this.data[x].ranges;

  for (let y in this.result) {

    for (let z of this.inputValues) {
      this.data[x].ranges[y].ph = z;
    }
  }
}
```

The first loop is looping through the data by index. This is much easier done by value as shown in my copy of your code above.

The second loop is looping through all of the results by index ... then for each result it is updating the `.ph` *multiple* times because within that loop you are looping through all of the `inputValues`. That is why it results in always the last value.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `forin` and a `for` in javascript/typescript. forin is not the same as say a `foreach` in C# or PHP.

```
let myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for(let keys in myObject) {
  // goes through all the keys of an object (i.e. a,b,c)
}

let myArray = [1,2,3];
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  // goes through the indexes of an enumerable array (i.e. 0,1,2)
}
// Alternatively, you could also use 
myArray.forEach((value, index, array) => {
   // lists all the values  
}
```

It just seem like you don't fully understand `forin` yet. Go check the doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Oh yeah and `forof` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: I made some modifications to the stackblitz. can you check it?